# performance benefits using BINARY vs CHAR. Round 2: VARBINARY vs VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, performance

is it true that there are performance benefits (in inserting, comparing, etc) when using the BINARY compared to CHAR?

Similarly, VARBINARY is more performant than VARCHAR data types??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=char+varchar+mysql

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR(datatype)` is more performance than `VARCHAR`.

Atomic datatype is more performance because it is indexable.

Always use char, varchar when store text data because you can use like, concat,etc operation on varchar(datatype) or char(datatype).

Always use `BINARY(fixed)`, `VARBINARY(var)` when store binary data such as image, file, etc…